# XHR возвращает ошибку "err_connection_refused"

Tags: reactjs, nginx, xhr

На сервере находится несколько бэкенд сервисов, фронт на реакте. Фронт делает запросы на этот же самый сервер(домен) но на разные порты.

Тестировали на разных устройствах и разных операторах, все работает кроме нескольких компов в конкретном офисе: у них в консоле барузера(хром) ошибку выдает XHR при запросах, ошибка:

> "err_connection_refused"

Куда есть смысл копать? как убедиться, что проблема строго на стороне офиса? Прямую ссылку с GET запросом не открывает, но аналогичную ссылку с фронтом - открывает нормально.

p.s. как вариант, грешим на nginx.

Comment: Как убедиться что это фаервол?

Comment: Должны логироваться в событиях системы запросы, которые блокируются. Смотрите логирование на конкретных машинах, где запросы блокируются. Ошибка `err_connection_refused` - однозначно возникает по причине настроек сети. Будь то фаерволл или антивирус, или дополнительные слои защиты. Вообще, зайдите в брандмауэр и разрешите запросы на оперделенных портах, так исключите стандартные средства системы (это я про Windows).

Comment: Спасибо, проблема была решена именно этим способом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка `err_connection_refused` - однозначно возникает по причине настроек сети. Будь то фаерволл или антивирус, или дополнительные слои защиты. Необходимо, зайти в брандмауэр и разрешить запросы на оперделенных портах, так исключите стандартные средства операционной системы (это я про Windows).

Чтобы быстро открыть брандмауэр Windows необходимо нажать на сочетание клавиш «WIN+R» и вписать команду `firewall.cpl`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там выбрать пункт дополнительных настроек и настроить входящие и исходящие правила подключений к определенным портам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запросы, которые блокируются на уровне локальной сети должны логироваться в событиях системы. Смотрите логирование на конкретных машинах, где запросы блокируются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]